# BizTalk Rest HTTP 201 Handling

Tags: rest, http, biztalk, biztalk-2020

Is there any way that BizTalk treats response REST HTTP 201 status as 200 and not throws exceptions?

I've read that article [TNWiki Article Spotlight - BizTalk Server: REST Services Error Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wikininjas/tnwiki-article-spotlight-biztalk-server-rest-services-error-handling), but the WebRequestInterceptor code is missing in there.

Comment: That Codeplex solution has moved to GitHub https://github.com/wmmihaa/REST-Start-Kit-for-BizTalk

Comment: What version of BizTalk are you using, and what CU have you got installed?  I have not encountered the 201 being a problem

Comment: Not specific to Biztalk, but `201` is _not_ an error. Anything code starting with 2xx is a success. (with some asterisks).

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I use Biztalk 2020 without any CU. I was told that biztalk treats anything that isn't http 200 response as an exception. I'll check that and add more insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was wrong informed. Biztalk 2020 treats 20x codes as positive ones.